# Build OpenCV for Android with a Mac

Tags: android, macos, opencv, android-ndk

On a Mac I did a clone of OpenCV 3.4

`git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`

and I use on most recent stable Android environment 3.0.1

following https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/Building_OpenCV4Android_from_trunk

`export ANDROID_NDK=~/Development/android-ndk-r10b
cd ~/opencv
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..`

... this works, fine ! But build for Android

`cd ~/opencv/platform
./scripts/cmake_android_arm.sh`

it deliveres

> CMake Error at platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake:813 (message):
>     Specified Android native API level 'android-9' is not supported by your
>     NDK/toolchain.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.10.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:91 (include)
>     CMakeLists.txt:117 (project)

ok, I set this

`export ANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=14
./scripts/cmake_android_arm.sh`

and now I see

> CMake Error at platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake:813 (message):
>     Specified Android native API level 'android-14' is not supported by your
>     NDK/toolchain.

I hope someone has a hint for me, how to solve this

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Have you figured this out?